# How reliable are 250 m soil map data from soilgrids.org?

Tags: geospatial

I have 250 m soil map from [SoilGrids](https://www.soilgrids.org/). I need to extract the soil type for some districts to perform land suitability analysis. But not sure how reliable are they?. Any suggestions?

Comment: What level of reliability do you need? On what criteria? (for instance location accuracy, up-to-date-ness, etc)

Comment: I want to derive the soil type for districts in Vietnam for Land suitability purpose. How much this data would be reliable for this kind of research studies?

Comment: See also https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11130/global-european-soil-properties-database. Please edit a little bit more your question: what soil parameters do you need? Also, it is soilgrids.org, not soilgrid.org

Comment: have you even tried looking up where this data comes from?

Answer (score 3):

Reliability is derived from your beliefs, so there is no correct answer to this. All of the information behind the SoilGrids is linked from their site; you will have to decide for yourself it if is reliable enough. It seems like it, but this isn't my project.

SoilGrids data comes from the [SoilInfo app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/soilinfo/id895057724?mt=8), which you can find more about in the SoilsInfo app icon in the navigation. 
[SoilInfo app's about page](https://soilinfo-app.org/#/about) goes into detail about its purpose and how the data is acquired.
SoilInfo app is the mobile component of the Global Soil Information Facilities (GSIF), and exists to provide access to the data behind SoilGrids.
More information at these links:
[GSIF - Our Approach for Generating Open Soil Data](http://www.isric.org/explore/gsif)
[SoilInfo App — global soil data on your palm](http://www.isric.org/explore/soilinfo)
[SoilGrids — global gridded soil information](http://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids)
[WoSIS Soil Profile Database](http://www.isric.org/explore/wosis)

Comment: @P.Kim you're welcome! It's what I'm here for! If this answer suffices, will you please mark it correct? I could careless about the personal points, much more focused on getting the number of questions/answered questions ratio better. Thank you!